# StatusCode: 429 Too Many Requests when accessing onenotes hosted in sharepoint using APP

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I receive below response when I access one-note hosted in share-point.  How to over come this error?

```
{StatusCode: 429, ReasonPhrase: 'Too Many Requests', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-CorrelationId: b5a8785e-0260-43de-b3a5-da0e3b8d28a7
  X-UserSessionId: b5a8785e-0260-43de-b3a5-da0e3b8d28a7
  X-OfficeFE: OneNoteServiceFrontEndApi_IN_1
  X-OfficeVersion: 16.0.6701.1550
  X-OfficeCluster: wus-zzz.www.onenote.com
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-AuthenticatedUserId: ORGID-E8B97416-D14B-4F5D-9059-AF7E93AE7DA1
  OData-Version: 4.0
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONi TELi CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDi OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR"
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Date: Wed, 03 Feb 2016 19:43:34 GMT
  Content-Length: 153
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true; IEEE754Compatible=false
  Expires: -1
}}
```

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: Was there a body in the request?

Answer (score 0):

Did you (or any app on your behalf) have couple requests issued at around the same time? If so, then you need to ensure not to flood the API with requests.

Comment: Hi Sharad, How one-note client is handling the scenario?  When we first synchronize one-note hosted in sharepoint in local system using onenote client there has to be large number of request to share point but we don't see 429. Does one-note client use different set of API's?

Comment: OneNote app sync is at low level and does not use same API as the one developer is using. I recommend issuing multiple requests for a given user couple seconds apart to avoid being throttled.